# How to get byte array of selected document?

Tags: javascript, jsom, csom

I have a javascript function where I would like to get the byte array of the selected documents. How to do that?

```
function DoSomething() 
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list;
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var totalSelectedItems = CountDictionary(selectedItems);

    if (totalSelectedItems > 0) 
    {
        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);

        for (i in selectedItems) 
        {
            var item = list.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            // Get document byte array, but how??
        }
    }   
}
```

In c# code you do it like this:

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("http://moss.dev.com/dropofflibrary/test1.docx");
byte[] bytes = file.OpenBinary();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileOpenBinaryStream) to get the binary stream:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<web-url>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<server relative url for file>')/openbinarystream",
    type: "GET",
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[SP.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246089(v=office.15).aspx) does not provide any method to get file as binary/byte. There is a method called [saveBinary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj838377.aspx) that helps to save binary data only.

If you need it badly, then try to solve it in the following way

- Create a web service. Web service will convert file into byte
- Now call this web service using javascript